# SQL LogCat error

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public Button save, view;
    public EditText name, phnnumber, mail, dejignation;
    DataBaseHelper dBaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializedAll();

        dBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                save(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void initializedAll() {

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
        view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewbutton);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        phnnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
        dejignation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dejignation);

    }

    public void save(View v) {

        String nam = name.getText().toString();
        String numb = phnnumber.getText().toString();
        String mai = mail.getText().toString();
        String dez = dejignation.getText().toString();

        Employe employe = new Employe(nam, mai, numb, dez);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), employe.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        long inserted = dBaseHelper.insertEmployr(employe);
        if (inserted >= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data inserted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data insertion failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}



public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "task_magment";
    public static final int DB = 1;

    public static final String EMPLOYETABLE = "e";
    public static final String IDFIELD = "id";
    public static final String NAMEFIELD = "name";
    public static final String EMAILFIELD = "email";
    public static final String PHNFIELD = "phone";
    public static final String DEJIGNATIONFIELD = "dejignation";

    public static final String EMPLOYEETABLESQL = "CREATE TABLE"
            + EMPLOYETABLE + "(" + IDFIELD + "INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY,"
            + NAMEFIELD + "TEXT," + EMAILFIELD + "TEXT," + PHNFIELD
            + "TEXT," + DEJIGNATIONFIELD + "TEXT)";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DB);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // create tebil
        db.execSQL(EMPLOYEETABLESQL);
        //Log.e("TABLE CREATE", EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertEmployr(Employe employe) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAMEFIELD, employe.getName());
        values.put(PHNFIELD, employe.getPhn());
        values.put(EMAILFIELD, employe.getEmail());
        values.put(DEJIGNATIONFIELD, employe.getDesignation());
        long inserted = db.insert(EMPLOYETABLE, null, values);
        db.close();
        return inserted;
    }

    // ///query

    public ArrayList<Employe> getAllEmploye() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run this apps and press the save button then apps crashed.

In LogCat it shows that

> (1) near "TABLEe": syntax error.

But I don't find any error.

How I can I resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no space between `CREATE TABLE` and table name!

Answer (score 1):

Error is here You forgot space between fields and field datatype also space after `CREATE TABLE`

```
public static final String EMPLOYEETABLESQL = "CREATE TABLE"
    + EMPLOYETABLE + "(" + IDFIELD + "INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY,"
    + NAMEFIELD + "TEXT," + EMAILFIELD + "TEXT," + PHNFIELD
    + "TEXT," + DEJIGNATIONFIELD + "TEXT)";
```

After Create table you forgot space at initial level take care of spaces

```
public static final String EMPLOYEETABLESQL = "CREATE TABLE "
    + EMPLOYETABLE + " ( " + IDFIELD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
    + NAMEFIELD + " TEXT, " + EMAILFIELD + " TEXT, " + PHNFIELD
    + " TEXT, " + DEJIGNATIONFIELD + " TEXT)";
```

I solved your initial problem of spaces see if there are error regarding space.

**UPDATE**

Here also problems

1. `IDFIELD = "id";` value of this field should be `"_id"`
2. While creating table you have not set ID feild as `AUTOINCREMENT`. **So** either you need to set ID field as AUTOINCREMENT or you need to insert value of this because it is primary key.

**NEW QUERY WIL BE LIKE THIS**

```
public static final String EMPLOYEETABLESQL = "CREATE TABLE "
    + EMPLOYETABLE + " ( " + "_id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + NAMEFIELD + " TEXT, " + EMAILFIELD + " TEXT, " + PHNFIELD
    + " TEXT, " + DEJIGNATIONFIELD + " TEXT)";
```

Might this will fixes your ISSUES.

Comment: What error you got now ? is the same error or different? if different then update your question

Answer (score 1):

Just change the EMPLOYEETABLESQL to

```
EMPLOYEETABLESQL = "CREATE TABLE "
    + EMPLOYETABLE + " ( " + IDFIELD + " INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY, "
    + NAMEFIELD + " TEXT, " + EMAILFIELD + " TEXT, " + PHNFIELD
    + " TEXT, " + DEJIGNATIONFIELD + " TEXT)";
```

Tip: Next time you try executing a query from java code,
 try printing out the query into the console or logcat right after you made them so that you can copy the query and execute it right from the MySQL command line to see if there is an error.

Comment: What is the error now? Did you try printing it in the console and execute the query from the mySQL command line? Do note I've made minor changes to my original answer..